# Drop down menu appearing behind images

Tags: php, html, css

I can't for the life of me figure out why the drop down when hovering over the "about" menu item is appearing behind the images, see this link http://www.ziprfit.com.au/index.php (I hope it's OK to post the link).

All search results suggest z-index, well the z-index for the images in there goes to 6, and I've set the menu to 100 and it still appears behind the images.

On the server side this is generated by PHP.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i dont see the problem are you using google chrome?

Comment: Yes. I just tried firefox too. Both running on Linux Mint.

Comment: Sorry, did I miss out some detail, the about box drop down is what does not show up (when you hover)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **position: relative;** in your  **#nav ul ul**

```
#nav ul ul {
z-index: 100;
display: none;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: relative;` and `z-index: 100;` to your `#nav` div :)